# Too Many elements on a card(mobile) clickable

Tags: gui-design, mobile-application, human-interface-guideline, cards

[image: Updated Card design after prioritizing]Is it recommended to use less clickable events on a card when you are designing for a mobile app.
I am designing a card , and client requirements are most of the information has to be on card.and there are lots of cliks(icons).
What are your suggestions.
and 
Which position do you suggest for CTA on card.
I wanted card to be same on both iOS and Android.

Feedbacks please[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to have less clickable elements in *any* UI (See [Hick's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hick%27s_law), [Rational Choice Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_choice_theory), and [Analysis Paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis)).

These effects can be concetrated in small areas such as mobile-based card UI.

For your specific case, I suggest you run some task-based user tests on your UI paying particular attention to accuracy (how often the user is forced to retrace steps to acheive the task) and time (how quickly the user can acheive the task.

Comment: Please check updated new card

Answer (score 1):

Harshith, you will have to prioritize and re prioritize to have only a selected items displayed on the card at the first glance. The remaining/ less important info can be shown when the user clicks on the card.

Having all information upfront, is definitely one of the bad ways of doing this excercise.

It would be wise to spend good amount of time thinking about "most important" data elements and have only those on card up front.

In terms of the CTA, it would really depend on the use case. Secondly, i would see this work flow as below:

1. Have your cards as the first step. But ensure only the most critical data elements are displayed. This data should be enough for the user to decide that he wants to "know more"
2. Once the user clicks on the card wanting to "know more", you should display the other data elements
3. On the same screen, at the bottom or top, you should have your CTA

Comment: please check updated new card

Answer (score 1):

You can have a lot of info on the card - dependant of what is useful for the user. But there should not be many clickable items, as the other answers says.

I.e. you can make the whole card clickable - which leads you to a new view where the user can lookup additional info.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've some suggestions:

1.You can put "funder" below the picture like you've done in 2nd draft.

2.The social apps make a heavy visual on the left side, maybe you can change them into "Go to website" instead, like what you have done in 1st draft and place it onto the left side of the primary CTA (in bottom right) as a flat button/ghost button?

3.I don't think putting a blue frame with the image is a great decision, maybe you can change the color into neutral color like soft grey?

4.You can reduce the spacing between text "Founded year" and "2011" ETC, thus they will more obvious to the user (I concern about this one, how do you deal with this when on 320px resolution).

5.You can resize "Bangalore IND" to make more pleasant to the eyes.

6.I think you need to change the color of your CTA to orange,& red, because the color seems not really appealed eventhough it is floating